# NEAR Protocol Total Transaction Fees Calculation

Tags: nearprotocol

Hi I was wondering how to calculate the total amount of transaction fees paid on NEAR.

According to the [Nomicon docs](https://nomicon.io/RuntimeSpec/Fees/), The total transaction fee is the sum of the following:

- A fee for creation of the receipt
- A fee for every action

But to determine the actual fee in $NEAR, I need to multiply the above to the gas price which changes every block.

So basically I get the below:

```
gas_price * (fee_for_creation_of_receipt + fee_for_every_action)
```

Now, what is confusing to me is that the fact that NEAR distributes 30% of their fees to the smart contract creators. Does this mean I only get 70% of all transaction fees if I follow the above equation?

I tried to explain how NEAR Protocol charges gas fees and wanted to get an answer if I should consider the 30% distribution to smart contract creators.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to calculate exactly.

- **Total fees paid**: Do not subtract the 30% contract reward, the users do pay for it after all.
- **Total fees burned**: You need to subtract the 30% contract reward but only for function call actions.

### Example

Suppose a transaction is executed with actions

```json
[
    CreateAccount("alice.near"),
    FunctionCall("main")
]
```

The gas fees are as follows:

- (block 1 gas price) * (receipt creation gas cost + CreateAccount send gas cost + FunctionCall send gas cost)
- (block 2 gas price) * (receipt execution gas cost + CreateAccount execution cost + FunctionCall base execution cost + dynamic function call execution cost)

If we plug in some example numbers for demonstration:

- block 1: 0.0001Ⓝ/Tgas * (0.11Tgas + 0.1Tgas + 2.3Tgas) = 0.000251Ⓝ
- block 2: 0.0001005Ⓝ/Tgas * (0.11Tgas + 0.1Tgas + 2.3Tgas + 10Tgas) = 0.001257255Ⓝ

So the total tokens paid for gas is 0.001508255Ⓝ.

The contract reward is calculated only on the dynamic function call execution part. All actions costs, including the constant base fee for a function call action required to start executing a function call, is not factored in.
Therefore, contract reward = 0.3 * 10Tgas * 0.0001005Ⓝ/Tgas = 0.0003015Ⓝ.

The remainder is 0.000955755Ⓝ. It gets burned. (Not paid to validators as often misunderstood because other protocols do it that way.)

Finally, note that the contract reward is only paid if the account is not deleted in the same transaction. Otherwise, it also get burned because there is no account that could receive it left.